# Hibernate session.createQuery error while replace method with single quote

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsf

I got very typical issue. My dynamically generated query like this...

```
UPDATE Templates t SET t.TEMPLATE_DATA =  replace(t.TEMPLATE_DATA, 'Test\'s&#32;Test', 'Kent&quot;s Test'), t.TEMPLATE_DATA =  replace(t.TEMPLATE_DATA, 'Test&amp;quot;s&amp;#32;Test', 'Kent&quot;s Test'), UPDATE_DATE = NOW() where PRACTICE_ID = 1 AND CATEGORY_ID IN (1)
```

This works perfect when I explictily fire this query in db. but by using hibernate's session.createQuery(-- my query --) if thwows an error **QueryTranslatorException**.

```
Database : Mysql 5.3
```

Have any one faced this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run this in Hibernate as native SQL query:

```
session.createSQLQuery(-- query text --);
```

Because if you use

```
session.createQuery(-- query text --);
```

Hibernate will try to execute it as HQL query which differs from usual SQL query.

HQL is object oriented query language. It operates in terms of objects rather then in terms of tables. [Here posted a brief description](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-sql-and-hql/) of difference between SQL and HQL. But if you have time better to read appropriate sections of hibernate's documentation about [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) and [Native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) usage.

Comment: Ohh great both of you are right. Thanks.
But really I want to understand what is difference between both? and by the way either it is HQL or simple SQL both fire on same backend MySql. Even does it matters?

Comment: YES! because HQL and SQL are with different syntax. HQL is at class-level and SQL is table-level

Comment: I edited my unswer. There you can find a brief description of deffierence between HQL and SQL.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute `SQL Query` in hibernate, Use : [session.createSQLQuery(String query);](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createSQLQuery%28java.lang.String%29)